# Is there a way to add an vertical line in a Blazor Chart?

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor, mudblazor

Hello I am practicing with Blazor and MudBlazor. Does anyone know a way to display a vertical line in a BlazorChart? I guess its working with `<CustomGraphics></CustomGraphics>` but i just don't know how. Has anyone tried it yet?

The vertical line stands for a upper or lower border.

```
<MudChart ChartOptions="@(new() { ChartPalette = new[] { "#9E9E9E" } })" ChartType="ChartType.Bar" ChartSeries="@Series" @bind-SelectedIndex="Index" XAxisLabels="@XAxisLabels" Width="100%" Height="300px">
<CustomGraphics>
???
</CustomGraphics>
</MudChart>
```

In the docs, they only play around with some text:

```
<MudChart ChartType="ChartType.Bar" ChartSeries="@Series" XAxisLabels="@XAxisLabels" Width="100%" Height="350px">
    <CustomGraphics>
        <style>
            .heavy { font: bold 30px Helvetica; }
            .Rrrrr { font: italic 40px Helvetica; fill: rgb(62,44,221); }
        </style>
        <text x="80" y="35" class="heavy">I Love</text>
        <text x="105" y="70" class="Rrrrr">MudBlazor!</text>
    </CustomGraphics>
</MudChart>
```

https://mudblazor.com/components/barchart#custom-svg-content

Any other hints are very welcome.

Comment: Where do you want to place the vertical lines? Depending on what you want It is maybe worth to have a look at other chart libraries.

Comment: for example a vertical line on x=1 and x=30 to y-max each

Comment: Something like this https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYcRFGlfzPpkMWQS ?
You could use path elements to draw the line manually.

Comment: yes that is what i am talking about, but how to align those lines onto a x-axis variable

Comment: After having again a look at it, I found that setting ChartOptions="new() { XAxisLines = true }" will enable the vertical lines on all x-axis values. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckwxFGltSzVbfHFt